# Как создать треугольники CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3

На сайте: [CSS Tricks - Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) есть множество различных форм CSS, и я особенно озадачен треугольником.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-up"></div>
```

**Как и почему это работает?**

Прим. переводчика

Я выбрал этот относительно простой вопрос для перевода, так как меня заинтересовали ответы, которые очень наглядно, подробно и доходчиво объясняют технику реализации фигур CSS. Ответов много, планирую в дальнейшем добавить переводы других  интересныx ответов из этого топика Enso.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/7394871) от участника  [@Stanislav Shabalin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417810/stanislav-shabalin).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/7073484/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел тот топик, такого варианта там нет:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 50%, red 51%);
  transform: skew(-25.5deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### CSS Треугольники: трагедия в пяти действиях

Как сказал [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work/7073503#7073503), границы одинаковой ширины расположены друг против друга под углом 45 градусов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда у вас нет верхней границы, это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем вы устанавливаете фигуре ширину `0` ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... и высоту `0` ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результатом будет треугольник:

```css
#triangle-up {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-up"></div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7073558/7394871) от участника  [@sdleihssirhc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317849/sdleihssirhc).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

**Вариант реализации с псевдоэлементами**

Сделав еще один шаг, используя `css` на основе этого, я добавил стрелки `назад` `вперед` и следующие кнопки:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
  margin:20px auto;
}

.triangle-down {
  border-bottom:none;
  border-top: 100px solid red;
}

.triangle-left {
  border-left:none;
  border-right: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-right {
  border-right:none;
  border-left: 100px solid red;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
}

.triangle-after:after {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  margin:0 5px;
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
}

.triangle-after-right:after {
  border-right:none;
  border-left: 5px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;

}

.triangle-before:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
  margin:0 5px;
  content:"";
  display:inline-block;
}

.triangle-before-left:before {
  border-left:none;
  border-right: 5px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;

}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<div class="triangle triangle-down"></div>
<div class="triangle triangle-left"></div>
<div class="triangle triangle-right"></div>

<a class="triangle-before triangle-before-left" href="#">Back</a>
<a class="triangle-after triangle-after-right" href="#">Next</a>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8681894/7394871) от участника  [@PseudoNinja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588005/pseudoninja).</sub>